# WPF(C#): Controller Right Joystick to Arrow Keys

Tags: c#, wpf, sharpdx

I'm using SharpDx and X-input to get my Xbox Controller's input but I'm having trouble finding to simulate the right arrow key when I move my right joystick right. This is what I got so far. My issue is when I move the stick to the right it presses the arrow key more than once so I tried to set up a thread.sleep to make it press every second but did not work. Kinda running out of ideas and would really appreciate some help.

```
public class XboxController
{
    private const int V = 2_000;
    private Controller _controller;
    private IMouseSimulator _mouseSimulator;
    private IKeyboardSimulator _keyboardSimulator;
    private Timer _timer;
    private bool _wasADown;
    public int deadband = 2500;

    private const int RefreshRate = 60;
    

    public XboxController()
    {

        _controller = new SharpDX.XInput.Controller(UserIndex.One);
        _mouseSimulator = new InputSimulator().Mouse;
        _keyboardSimulator = new InputSimulator().Keyboard;
        _timer = new Timer(obj => Update());
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void Start()
    {

        _timer.Change(0, 1000 / RefreshRate);
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        _controller.GetState(out var state);
        Movement(state);
        Scroll(state);
        LeftButton(state);
        RightButton(state);
        Stick(state);
    }

    private void RightButton(State state)
    {

        if (state.Gamepad.Buttons == GamepadButtonFlags.B)
        {
            _keyboardSimulator.KeyPress(WindowsInput.Native.VirtualKeyCode.BACK);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

    }

    private void LeftButton(State state)
    {
        var isADown = state.Gamepad.Buttons.HasFlag(GamepadButtonFlags.A);
        if (isADown && !_wasADown) _mouseSimulator.LeftButtonDown();
        if (!isADown && _wasADown) _mouseSimulator.LeftButtonUp();
        _wasADown = isADown;
    }

    private void Scroll(State state)
    {
        var x = state.Gamepad.RightThumbX / 10000;
        var y = state.Gamepad.RightThumbY / 10000;

        _mouseSimulator.HorizontalScroll(x);
        _mouseSimulator.VerticalScroll(y);
    }

    private void Movement(State state)
    {
        var x = state.Gamepad.LeftThumbX / 2500;
        var y = state.Gamepad.LeftThumbY / 2500;

        _mouseSimulator.MoveMouseBy(x, -y);
    }
    private void Stick(State state)
    {



        while ((state.Gamepad.RightThumbX) > 0)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            _keyboardSimulator.KeyPress(WindowsInput.Native.VirtualKeyCode.RIGHT);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
}
```